# upload to google cloud storage signed url with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

With the following code I'm able to upload to my publicly writable bucket in google cloud storage. (allUsers has write permission). However If the bucket isn't publicly writable then I get a 401 unauthorised error. (I don't want the bucket to be publicly writable).

```
var file = $scope.myFile;
      var fileData = file;
      var boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
      var delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
      var close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
        var metadata = {
          'name': 'objectName', //'lol' + fileData.name,
          'mimeType': contentType
        };

        var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
        var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
          '\r\n' +
          base64Data +
          close_delim;
        var stuff = angular.fromJson('{"Expires": "1415344534", "GoogleAccessId": "394062384276-n2jjh17vt975fsi4nc9ikm1nj55466ir@developer.gserviceaccount.com", "Signature": "AMkhO7mt2zg+s1Dzx28yQIMSrZlDC2Xx1SzvMCAgUVyiLXs5890/nA6PKzoc1KYBcRv/ALmkNaEVhvWHxE0EfcE151c0PYSG9x7AeSpQI/3dB1UPcSqpwilS1e2sgwB9piLNvBEXLNRXiLYyTiH22zkFZHAEQonJ3J25a47fwo4="}');
        var Expires = stuff.Expires;
        var GoogleAccessId = stuff.GoogleAccessId;
        var Signature = encodeURIComponent(stuff.Signature);
        var BUCKET = 'mybucket';
        var request = $window.gapi.client.request({
          'path': '/upload/storage/v1/b/' + BUCKET + '/o',
          'method': 'POST',
          'params': {
            'uploadType': 'multipart',
            'Expires': Expires,
            'GoogleAccessId': GoogleAccessId,
            'Signature': Signature
          },
          'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
          },
          'body': multipartRequestBody});

        request.execute(function(r) {
          console.log(r);
        })
      }
```

Is it possible to use signed URLS with the gapi javascript client? Or does it not understand the params.

If not - are there any examples of doing CORS with the JSON api from javascript for upload with signed urls?

(lets assume that my expiry, GoogleAccessId & Signature are correct & match what i'm doing in the javascript & the permissions i've set up on the bucket)

basically are there any examples of uploading to google cloud storage from javascript client from localhost without requiring the user to have a google account & without using a publicly writable bucket but using dispensed signed urls?

Comment: Hi Robert, I've been looking for the same thing. Did you manage to do this in the end?

Comment: I think I gave up and tried something else and then I found out my signed url was wrong all along - so it probably would have worked if i'd signed my url correctly. You can use gcutil to create a correct url and try that.

Comment: I did generate it with gsutil, but you can't use it with /upload/storage/v1, you have to send a PUT request which failed for me because of CORP policies, so I gave up and just made the bucket public for now.

Comment: ok well I just used angulars $http method. (had to upload a CORS.json file for my bucket - and I think i might have used PUT or POST)

Answer (score 1):

Use `https://storage.googleapis.com` as a host to compose the URL that points to the desired resource. You can choose between a few ways to construct your base URL. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#Assembling-the-URL) are some possible combinations.

For reference, you can also check out [a very simple snippet Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatformBook/code-snippets/blob/master/cloud-storage/signed-urls.py) that could be helpful.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was implementing the same issue. The problem is with SignedURL. After correcting the signedurl the upload worked like a charm.

As I was using php. Below is the code for generating signed urls.

```
private function createSignedUrl($objectName, $bucketName, $key, $serviceEmailAddress, $method = 'GET', $duration = 600)
{
    $expires = time() + $duration;

// Line breaks are important!
$toSign = (
    $method . "\n" .
    /* Content-MD5 */ "\n" .
    /* Content Type */ "\n" .
    $expires . "\n" .
    $objectName
);
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode(JWT::encode($toSign, $key, 'HS256')));
return array(
    'expires' => $expires,
    'accessid' => $serviceEmailAddress,
    'signature' => $signature,
);
}
```

Comment: Is this still working? I had it working in version 1.0 but after upgrading to 2.0 and try to to migrate it's not longer working. I am basically doing exactly as above